# Issue loading images from WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) directory into webpage loaded in Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

***TL/DR:***
Windows-based Chrome browser will load WSL2-based html file without issues but will not load embedded WSL2-based images due to unknown parsing issue which does not prepend "Ubuntu" to the filestring. Manually changing the image filestring through webpage inspection is a temporary fix, adding "Ubuntu" to the filestring while generating the html page does not fix the issue.

**Situation is as follows:**
After my data has been processed, I want to show the results in a webpage using a Jupyter Notebook.
Thus, I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML


# For showing images in Pandas DF
def path_to_image_html(path, windows = True):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="250" >'

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['img_guid', 'img_text', 'img_original', 'img_processed', 'img_filestring'])

for image_name in images.items():
    img_processed = process(img_original)
    data_output_dict = {
        'img_guid': [img_guid], 
        'img_text': [text.rstrip()], 
        'img_original': [path_to_image_html(img_original)],
        'img_processed': [path_to_image_html(img_processed)],
        'img_filestring': [img_filestring]
    }
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data_output_dict)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], ignore_index=True)

html_output = HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))

with open('html_file.html', 'w') as f: f.write(html_output.data)
```

**However, this is the result: (see image on Imgur --> [Example of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECMmI.png))**

So the webpage looks like I want it to, except that the images are not loaded. Their file path is `file://wsl.localhost/home/Oaknut/ProjectDir/img_dir/example_image.png`, whereas the html's file location is `file://wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/Oaknut/ProjectDir/html_file.html` - adding the missing `Ubuntu` bit of the image filestring *manually in the browser, using the html inspector* makes said image appear, but this is of course not a fix for the issue. Adding the line `if windows: path = 'Ubuntu' + path` to the `path_to_image_html` function displayed above does not fix the issue, since this will make the images (in the recompiled html file) have the file location `file://wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/Oaknut/ProjectDir/Ubuntu/home/Oaknut/ProjectDir/img_dir/example_image.png`.

- System set-up: Using Windows 11 with WSL2, running Python 3.8 in WSL2 through VScode installed on Windows (I need CUDA, hence the reason why I'm using WSL2), and am using Chrome on Windows.

**Edit:**
The value of the `img_original` variable (or the `img_processed` variable, for that matter) is `/home/Oaknut/ProjectDir/img_dir/example_img.png` (obviously not the original name, but adhering to the same file and folder structure for the minimum working example.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you append the `Ubuntu` folder using a raw-string? Something like this:

```py
if windows:
   path = rf'Ubuntu{path}'
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a clarifying question and therefore should be a comment on the original question.

Comment: The value is `/home/Oaknut/ProjectDir/img_dir/example_img.png` (note that these are example file names to cover up the real file names, and this is made for the minimum working example.)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post comments

Comment: @TonyMiri thanks for the suggestion and the updated answer, but unfortunately this does the exact same thing as what I tried earlier (see the paragraph under the code block in my original question with what I tried and the result of doing so).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).